# How to let crawler4j fetch page by relative path?

Tags: crawler4j

With Crawler4j, I can fetch page linked by a complete url, such as:

`<a href='http://www.domain.com/thelink'>`

However I found that if the link is relative, such as:

`<a href='/thelink'>`

Crawler4j will bypass this link(page), and I even have no chance to see the link in `shouldVisit(Page referringPage, WebURL url)` method.

I do not see any configuration about this in [Crawler4j Github page](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j), do I miss something?

Comment: You should consider to open an issue on the github page...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in the related [issue](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j/issues/143) on the project page, it seems that this behaviour is related to the fact, that this specific web-page does a lot of rendering content using ajax / javascript.

However, `crawler4j` is not able to render javascript styling on demand as it does not include a javascript engine for this purpose. In addition, the `script` tag is not scanned for URLS yet.

Comment: Thanks, rzo, I saw your analysis on Github issue page, it clears my puzzle.